# Automatic filling from manually made Excel forms for multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have designed a manual form in Excel (not using the Excel Form)
that links from cells in Sheet "Employee Form" to a dataset in the second sheet in the same file named "DataSet".

I managed to fill the first rows, but I can't figure out how to make it so that it can fill multiple rows after clicking a button.

So after finishing the form for employee A, the user can continue filling the form for employee B. Right now I can only make the form fill for one user only.

This is what I currently have now:

```
Sub Fill_form()
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
     Worksheets("DataSet").Range("A2:Y2").Copy
     Worksheets("DataSet").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Change the row argument after Y? E.g. Range("A2:Y4").Copy

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to use a loop:

```
Sub Fill_form()

    dim i as Long, LastRow as Long

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    LastRow = Sheets("DataSet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 to LastRow
        Worksheets("DataSet").Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy
        Worksheets("DataSet").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Hod, thanks for answering. Unfortunately it doesn't work here, it asks me to select a cell and pastes the contents in that cell. Then the new data doesn't get recorded, it just repeats the old data. Any idea why is this? Thanks!

Comment: @user71812 Can you paste a screenshot of how the worksheet looks like? The current state and desired state would be great.

Comment: Change `.Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i)` to `Cells(i, "A").Resize(, 25)` or `With Worksheets("DataSet"): .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i, "Y")).Copy: End With`